# property settings Configure a Term Set to be used for this property powershell

Tags: user-profile-property

I am creating a user profile propertie using powershell,
But in my case 'Configure a Term Set to be used for this property' gets disabled? After creating the propertie using powershell.
How could i activate the checkbox Configure a Term Set to be used for this property and set a termset there?

Answer (score 0):

Synchronization with Active Directory could be a issue. If you remove those fields from being synchronized with AD and check you'll probably be able to enable the check box.